# Bluetooth USB adapter setup

Tags: fedora, usb, bluetooth, bluez

I just bought a no-name BT 5.0 USB adapter and want to get started with it on my fedora 31 system.

When I attach the device:

```
$ dmesg
...
[ 2540.229893] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 2540.229947] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[ 2540.229948] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 2540.229951] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 2540.229952] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 2540.229954] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 2547.365398] usb 1-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 2547.457425] usb 1-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice=88.91
[ 2547.457428] usb 1-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2547.457429] usb 1-2.3: Product: USB1.1-A
[ 2547.509326] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[ 2547.553219] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 2547.553221] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 2547.553223] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 2683.026955] usb 1-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 2731.684584] usb 1-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 2742.277472] usb 1-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice=88.91
[ 2742.277481] usb 1-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3443.347982] usb 1-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 9
[ 3701.224445] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 3701.351900] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice=88.91
[ 3701.351903] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3701.351905] usb 1-9: Product: USB1.1-A
```

and:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
...
```

```
$ hciconfig 
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:11  ACL MTU: 679:9  SCO MTU: 48:16
        DOWN 
        RX bytes:574 acl:0 sco:0 events:30 errors:0
        TX bytes:368 acl:0 sco:0 commands:30 errors:0
```

**But:**

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
```

As a consequence, the adapter is not usable as tools like `blueman-manager` could *not* find it.

At first, I thought this a no-brainer as I have another BT 4.2 USB adapter that works without problems. For reference, this is the output for the *working* adapter:

```
$ dmesg
...
[ 4027.813778] usb 1-2.4: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 4027.826435] usb 1-2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c820, bcdDevice= 2.00
[ 4027.826444] usb 1-2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4027.826449] usb 1-2.4: Product: 802.11ac NIC
[ 4027.826453] usb 1-2.4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 4027.826456] usb 1-2.4: SerialNumber: 123456
[ 4028.056173] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[ 4028.057139] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[ 4028.057147] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[ 4028.062304] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[ 4028.062600] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 21678
[ 4028.474254] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x826ca99e
[ 4028.598199] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 4028.598213] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 4028.598332] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0bda:c820 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
...

$ hciconfig 
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: D0:C0:BF:B8:B7:67  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 255:12
        UP RUNNING PSCAN 
        RX bytes:1433 acl:0 sco:0 events:152 errors:0
        TX bytes:26695 acl:0 sco:0 commands:152 errors:0

$ hcitool dev
Devices:
        hci0    D0:C0:BF:B8:B7:67
```

Any idea how to get my new adapter working?

Comment: What if do you do `hciconfig hci0 up`? Any clue in dmesg?

Comment: `$ sudo hciconfig hci0 up` <br/>
Can't init device hci0: Operation not supported (95)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the adapter hardware `ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)`.

- There is a kernel bug report: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42932
- And a ubuntu entry (device 'Bluetake'): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsBluetoothUsbAdapters

At the end, it is a known problem for a very old (and likely) broken adapter hardware.